# How should I add Google Talk users as contacts in Adium?

Tags: google-talk, xmpp, adium

In Adium, I have a non-Google XMPP account.

If I want to add an XMPP Contact that is @gmail.com, do I add them as an "XMPP" contact or a "GTalk" contact? It gives both options.

edit: figured it out, you can add as an XMPP contact.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as XMPP contact as Google talk uses XMPP protocol in back ground.